# Determining the equations of motion for a 2 DOF in 2 directions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, string, vibrations

I'm having trouble understanding a 2DOF system that moves in 2 directions. The problem asks me to determine the EOM for a system shown in the attached image:

[image]

My first idea is to transform this system into a simpler one in which the two masses move in the same direction instead of the horizontal and vertical directions. I have determined that the displacement of $m_1$ is directly related to the rotation of the pulley due to the inextensible string.

Let $x$ be the displacement of $m_1$ and y be the displacement of $m_2$, therefore, $x=φr$ and $\dot x= \dot φr$.
However, I am confused as to how to relate the displacement of $m_2$ to the pulley. Additionally, I am having trouble understanding how to incorporate the inertial moment of the pulley into the EOM.

Any help would be appreciated, however, please do not give me a direct answer as I understand better if I am able to solve the problem with only hints and pointers.

Comment: Concerning your first paragraph, providing a drawing would be helpful showing how spring, masses and pulley are connected. Concerning your second paragraph, I think by your described simplification you loose the effect of gravitational potential energy.

Comment: I've attached a picture of the problem. Do you suggest using the energy method by equating kinetic energy to potential energy?

Comment: You cannot equate kinetic to potential energy. It is $E_\text{kin}+E_\text{pot}=\text{const}$, but not $E_\text{kin}=E_\text{pot}$. I would suggest using the Lagrangian method to find the EOM. But I don't know if your course has already introduced this method.

Comment: Hi Thomas, unfortunately not yet no. Do you suggest trying anything else? I'm really stuck on it.

Comment: From the free body diagram you can easy obtain the EOM‘s. How many degrees of freedom, this system has ?

Answer (score 0):

If the pulley has negligible moment of inertia or the string slides around it without friction then you can ignore the rotation of the pulley.

It will simplify the problem if you measure displacements and extensions of springs from the equilibrium position when mass 2 hangs freely. Neither mass is accelerating in the equilibrium position so the tension in the string and both springs is then $T_0=m_2 g$.

At some arbitrary time let the displacements of masses 1 and 2 from their equilibrium positions be $x$ and $y$. The extensions of springs 1 and 2 are then $x$ and $y-x$ so the tensions in them above the equilibrium value $T_0$ are $k_1 x$ and $k_2 (y-x)$. The accelerations of the masses are $\ddot x$ and $\ddot y$.

Apply Newton's 2nd Law of Motion to each mass :
$$m_2 \ddot y=-k_2 (y-x)$$
$$m_1 \ddot x=-k_1x+k_2(y-x)$$

The general solutions $x(t), y(t)$ of these coupled differential equations are superpositions of 2 **normal modes** in which $y=+ax$ and $y=-ax$ each with a different frequency. ($a$ is a constant.)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in trying to establish the equivalent mass of the pulley $m_p$ and place it inline with the rest of the system

[image: fig1]

You can work out what $m_p$ should be by taking the pulley at rest and applying a force $F$ on the edge of it to observe what acceleration $a$ that point sees

[image: fig2]

Now do the free-body diagram and place some unknown force $P$ at the pivot

[image: fig3]

and write the EOM for the pulley, and note that we are looking for the acceleration $a = -r \alpha$ as a vector to the right corresponds to a negative CW rotation.

$$\begin{aligned} F + P & = 0 \\
 -r \, F & = I_A \alpha \end{aligned}$$

with solution  $\alpha =  - \frac{r \,F}{I_A}$ which means

$$ F =  \underbrace{ \left(\frac{I_A}{r^2}\right) }_{m_p} \; a $$

so use $\boxed{m_p = \frac{I_A}{r^2}}$ in the idealized system.